# PCIe driver with V4L2/ALSA media frame work.

Tags: vlc, alsa, v4l2, mplayer

I'm designing video capture card using PCIe interface. PCIe device will have FPGA IP from xilinx and there is a PCIe 
reference driver from xilinx. Since device is a video capture card and there should be an application to display same.
Assuming, I will use either VLC or mplayer for displaying video data from PCIe driver. 
I should use media framework such as V4L2 and ALSA for video and audio respectively. 
I well receive raw video and audio data from FPGA through pci driver. video either it will be in planner YVU422  or YVU420 format.

From above information, I understood that driver should be (/dev/video) media driver (V4l2) not PCIe driver.

I have few question regarding this.

1) How to make driver  compatible with VLC/mPlayer application.

2) what is interface between VLC and V4L2 driver, which IOCTLS should I use for set and get

( Suppose I want to set resolution from VLC app to FPGA device using V4L2 driver)

3) In which way VLC/mplayer accept input video data, do I need to add any header(metadata) information to raw video data 
or not. whether VLC/mplayer accepts planner or packed YUV or not.

4) As of now I'm assuming that, ALSA will handle audio part, but how and when to invoke audio driver. How to maintain
sync between audio and video

Regards,

Kulkarni.